# Expected earn for throwing a fair die

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The question is
A player throwing a ordinary die is to recieve 1/2^n where n denotes the number of throws required to get the first 3 .Find the expectation.

The answer given in my book is 1/7

However when I solved it I got a different answer
My solution

The expected no of throws to get 3 is **6**

So the expected earn should be 1/2^6

Please someone kindly explain me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've fallen into the trap of assuming that $\ E\left(\frac{1}{2^N}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{E(N)}}\ $. The first of these quantities is the expected earnings, whereas it's the second that's $\ \frac{1}{2^6}\ $.  The probability that the first $3$ will appear on the $\ n$-th toss, and hence that the amount won will be $\ \frac{1}{2^n}\ $, is  $\ \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}\ $. Therefore, the expected earnings are
\begin{align}
E\left(\frac{1}{2^N}\right)&=
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) ^n\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{12\left(1-\frac{5}{12}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{7}\ .
\end{align}